# I was wondering what is meant by class state in OOP particularly in Python

Tags: python, oop

Today, someone asked me about static methods and said is that right that static method can't access or modify a class state?

Comment: It is the state of a class, which in Python is an instance of `type`, as distinct from the state of an instance of that class.

Comment: You would need to know the difference between a class and an object.

Comment: Read this: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/class

Comment: A static method _could_ access a class's state via the class's global name. It probably shouldn't. It doesn't automatically receive a reference to the class it is called on, as a class method does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

General OO answer: the state of an object is the values of it's attributes. For example, given

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


p = Point(42, 43)
```

then the state of `p` is `{"x": 42, "y": 43}`

To modify an object's state, a method need to have access to this object. For ordinary methods, this is provided by the `self` parameter.

Now Python's classes are objects too (instance of the `type` class), so Python has "classmethods" which can be invoked on either an instance or the class itself, but get the class object itself instead of an instance. Those classmethods can then modify the class's state (class attributes, which are shared by all instances of the class).

A staticmethod gets neither the instance nor class, so it can't change neither the class nor instance's state indeed.

Comment: I think staticmethod still able to access class variable.

class TestMethod:
    value=1

@staticmethod
def get_value_static():
    return TestMethod.value

This is why I still confuse why staticmethod exist if it behave similar to classmethod. Maybe just naming sake so programmer aware that staticmethod should not touch class var while classmethod allowed? Pls correct me if I'm wrong.